# what is the htaccess rule and condition to redirect one specific url to another subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have site say https://example.com . I want just one url of it to redirect its subdomain. that is https://example.com/user/login  redirect to https://subdomain.example.com/user/login  (this is cname of main domain)

is it possible through htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

For such a case, just have the specific URL as an anchored (`^...$`) pattern

```
RewriteRule ^user/login$ https://subdomain.example.com/user/login [L]
```